# Laravel4 Seeding in testing environment fails using SQLite, while succeeds using mysql

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, seeding

**In short**: seeding is working fine with mysql while breaks with sqlite. The broken code is like `DB::table('user')->insert($users);`

Seed code:

```
<?php
public function run() {
    DB::table('user')->delete();
    $users = array();
    $birth = new DateTime('1980-03-12');
    while ($i++ < 50) {
        $users[$i]['email'] = "mail$i@example.com";
        $users[$i]['password'] = User::password('test');
        $users[$i]['enabled'] = 1;
        $users[$i]['name'] = 'Name';
        $users[$i]['surname'] = 'Surname';
        $users[$i]['birthDate'] = $birth;
    }
    DB::table('user')->insert($users); //<- This line is broken when using sqlite.
}
```

My default database driver is **mysql**, now i am trying to switch to **sqlite** for the testing environment. So, under

> app/config/testing/database.php

i have this config, inside 'connections' ('default' key is 'sqlite')

```
'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
```

Now, if i issue

> php artisan migrate --seed, **this is working fine.**

If i issue

> php artisan migrate --seed --env=testing, **this is NOT working**

The `DB::table('user')->insert($users);` above is failing, infact when i comment that out the seeding works fine.
The error at command line is

> ErrorException","message":"array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be
>   array, null given [...]
>   /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/SQLiteGrammar.php","line":52

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at line 52 we find:

```
$names = $this->columnize(array_keys($values[0]));
```

This is used to build the column list part of the query (`INSERT INTO (column1, column2) VALUES...`)

`$values` is in your case `$users`, but it does not have a `0` index. Why? 
`while ($i++ < 50)` increments $i before entering the loop body so the first index of `$users` will be `1`, not `0` as the Laravel SQLite `insert` implementation needs.

Fix it like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 49) {
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

Why does the MySQL implementation work?
This is what the corresponding line looks like in this implementation:

```
$columns = $this->columnize(array_keys(reset($values)));
```

Comment: If anyone is interested I submitted a pull request for this https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/2405